# logical fallacy: X is not wrong, if you have done X

Tags: logic, fallacies

My friend on facebook posted this statement:

> 'Looting is wrong' say citizens living on stolen land, built by stolen
>   labour, powered by stolen resources from poor countries.

[image]

So it sounds like her argument is that because citizens live on stolen land, built by stolen labour, powered by stolen resources from poor countries, looting is not wrong?

The structure of this statement feels flawed, but I don't know enough about fallacies to pinpoint which fallacy it is, if indeed that's the case. I've been searching around and can't place it.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure that this is best read as an argument.  I think it is better read as an accusation of hypocrisy.  If we try to turn it into an argument it is more likely "You have no right to criticize".  It is a version of not casting the first stone.

Comment: Is "You have no right to criticize" generally considered a valid argument?

Comment: No.  "You have no right to criticize." is a sentence.  In order to think it is an argument I need to see premises and a conclusion.

Comment: My first comment was  incorrect.  What I should have said it that If we want to turn it into an argument, the conclusion is probably "You have no right to judge." or something similar. The premise is something like "Anyone who benefits from a past wrongdoing has no right to criticize those who now commit the same wrong."

Comment: "Property is theft" is along the same lines: it extends the definition of a word far beyond it's original meaning. Your friend has a point, but "stolen land" (from whom? who legitimately owns a given piece of land?), "stolen labor" (needs to clarify), "stolen resources" (needs to clarify) are only metaphorically stealing, where as looting is literal stealing.

Comment: @barrycarter maybe slavery is only metaphorically stolen labour when it's enforced by law, and colonisation only metaphorically stolen land when the colonised have no notion of land property in their culture, but I'm not sure they're morally better than literal stealing (particularly when one is in need). Moral and law are not the same. Having said that I don't think people should be held responsible for their ancestors actions...

Comment: @QuentinRuyant OK, I guess the best answer to this question is "false analogy". Comparing stealing here and now in the present to benefiting from an ancestor's legal (though immoral) actions isn't a good direct analogy. I agree there are moral issues, but to compare the two as though they were identical is fallacious. You could also go with "two wrongs don't make a right"

Comment: @barrycarter agreed. But I also agree with JimH 's reading that the comment is more on whether one has the right to judge

Comment: The fallacy you mention in the title is **tu quoque** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_quoque), or as @JimH notes, an appeal to hypocrisy. However, the actual description is a false (or at least hyperbolic) analogy, and possibly some sort of "transitive" fallacy (if X hurts Y, then Y can hurt Z), but haven't found a name for that one yet.

Comment: The closest to the "transitive" fallacy I could find on http://utminers.utep.edu/omwilliamson/ENGL1311/fallacies.htm is #71: "moral licensing", but it doesn't really apply directly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I would say there is a fallacy here.

The message I get from the statement is that there is equal wrong doing here not a comparison of which is right.   The statement suggests all of the acts are equally wrong.  So how can you single out one act as wrong and not the others.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the family of [tu quoque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_quoque). It's especially fallacious as, unlike the standard tu quoque, the target didn't perform the acts, just benefits from them. So it has elements of whatsaboutism and Two Wrongs Make a Right. There's also [equivocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation) between looting, which is taking property in violation of a well-established legal system, versus "theft" being used in a more metaphorical sense of behavior that the writer subjectively feels is "unfair".

Answer (score 1):

> logical fallacy: X is not wrong, if you have done X

Arguments like these are frequent and odd.

Technically the statement is saying that the listener's actions form the standard of right and wrong. Action X is right, or at least it is not wrong, because the listener does the same thing.

In its own backwards way, this argument is an appeal to authority; here, the authority is not a third party, but the listener themselves. The listen presumably agrees with their own values.

Also, as pointed out in other answers, the argument is plain old *tu quoque*. Yeah, maybe Action X is wrong, but all of that is beside the point because the listener does it, too. The response just evades the question.

If this form of argument were banished from cable news programs, a lot of panel discussions would have to fold. Or maybe address issues directly.